# Get all records with maximum Date value parallel to selecting by condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am querying database and retrieving all columns that share 32485 `ProjectNumber`.
I need to get all the maximum `ChangeDateTime` of each `orderId`.

**DataBase Table:**

```
OrderID     ProjectNumber     ChangeDateTime
---------------------------------------------
1                32485        30/11/2018
1                32485        29/11/2018
1                32485        28/11/2018
2                32485        30/09/2017
2                32485        29/09/2017
2                32485        28/09/2017
```

**Desierd Result:**

```
OrderID     ProjectNumber     ChangeDateTime
---------------------------------------------
1                32485        30/11/2018 
2                32485        30/09/2017
```

**What i have tried so far (but i am not surprised it only returns 1 record with the max ChangeDateTime):**

```
SELECT TOP 1 
Orders.OrderID,
Changes.ChangeDateTime,
Orders.ProjectNumber
FROM Orders 
INNER JOIN Changes ON Changes.ItemID = Orders.OrderID
INNER JOIN LineStatusSettings ON 
Cast( LineStatusSettings.LineStatusSettingID as varchar(max)) = Changes.NewValue 
INNER JOIN LineStatuses ON LineStatuses.LineStatusID= LineStatusSettings.LineStatusID
INNER JOIN OrderTypes ON OrderTypes.OrderTypeID = LineStatusSettings.OrderTypeID
WHERE Orders.ProjectNumber = 32485 AND Orders.Deleted=0 
GROUP BY Orders.OrderID,
Changes.ChangeDateTime,
Orders.ProjectNumber
ORDER BY Changes.ChangeDateTime DESC
```

Comment: Left justified SQL is so hard to read.

Comment: You select 8 columns, but only 3 are returned. Strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting too complex. This query produces the desired output:

```
SELECT
  Orders.OrderID,
  Orders.ProjectNumber,
  MAX(Changes.ChangeDateTime)
FROM Orders 
INNER JOIN Changes ON Changes.ItemID = Orders.OrderID
WHERE 
  Orders.ProjectNumber = 32485
GROUP BY
  Orders.OrderID,
  Orders.ProjectNumber
```

If you need the other stuff in the JOIN area, for purposes of restricting the rows considered for output, it can be added in

```
SELECT
  Orders.OrderID,
  Orders.ProjectNumber,
  MAX(Changes.ChangeDateTime)
FROM Orders 
  INNER JOIN Changes ON Changes.ItemID = Orders.OrderID
  INNER JOIN LineStatusSettings ON Cast( LineStatusSettings.LineStatusSettingID as varchar(max)) = Changes.NewValue 
  INNER JOIN LineStatuses ON LineStatuses.LineStatusID= LineStatusSettings.LineStatusID
  INNER JOIN OrderTypes ON OrderTypes.OrderTypeID = LineStatusSettings.OrderTypeID
WHERE Orders.ProjectNumber = 32485 AND Orders.Deleted=0 
GROUP BY
  Orders.OrderID,
  Orders.ProjectNumber
```

If you add more columns to the output, and theyre not in some aggregate function (min/max/avg/sum/count etc) then you'll need to add them to the group by too, and it will probably increase the number of rows, because it increases the number of unique combinations of values

An alternative way to efficiently get a load of data, and select the "TOP x based on just a few columns" would be like this:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
 SELECT
  *,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Orders.OrderID, Orders.ProjectNumber ORDER BY Changes.ChangeDateTime DESC) as rown
 FROM Orders 
  INNER JOIN Changes ON Changes.ItemID = Orders.OrderID
  INNER JOIN LineStatusSettings ON Cast( LineStatusSettings.LineStatusSettingID as varchar(max)) = Changes.NewValue 
  INNER JOIN LineStatuses ON LineStatuses.LineStatusID= LineStatusSettings.LineStatusID
  INNER JOIN OrderTypes ON OrderTypes.OrderTypeID = LineStatusSettings.OrderTypeID
 WHERE Orders.ProjectNumber = 32485 AND Orders.Deleted=0 
 --ORDER BY Orders.OrderID, Orders.ProjectNumber, Changes.ChangeDateTime DESC 
)a
WHERE
  a.rown = 1
```

This doesnt group the data, it just joins everything together. Then the ROW_NUBMER clause effectively breaks the data up into blocks per unique occurrnce of an OrderID/PrijectNumber pairing, and sets up a counter that starts at 1 for the most recent date per pairing, and increases by 1. A different OrderID/ProjectNumber pairing causes the counter to retart from 1.. This means there will be a row number of 1 for (OrderID 1,ProjectNumber 1) another row numbered 1 for (OrderID 2, Project 1), another one numbered 1 for (OrderID 1, ProjectNumber 2)

It's easier to see how it works if you just run the subquery in isolation.. I recommend that you uncomment the ORDER BY line if running in isloation as it will ensure the results are presented in an order that makes it easy to see what's going on (the counter restarting from 1 when the pairing changes)

Comment: you wrote"...and it will probably increase the number of rows, because it increases the number of unique combinations of values..."do you think using a nested select in order to extract the other columns is the most efficient way or that there is a better way?

Comment: It depends what other columns you want; sometimes it won't increase the number of rows, as it won't introduce any new combinations of pairs of values.. There are alternative tricks if you have a lot of columns, typically using `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY x ORDER BY y)` - i'll add an example..

Comment: Note; I've not tested any of the queries here, as I haven't any example data or tables, so you might need to do a bit of debugging. If you get a point where flat out you can't make it work, let me know of any eroror

Answer (score -1):

Use `TOP 1 WITH TIES`:

```
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES . . .
```